# Android ADB not detecting device

Tags: android, adb

There's absolutely heaps of these questions out there, all with a seemingly random assembly of answers that don't really talk about why, and don't offer anything that at least covers ALL of the reasonable approaches.

I'm running ADB on OSX, but I've got other team members using Linux (Ubuntu) and I occasionally use Windows.  OS doesn't really seem to matter, so long as the relevant USB driver has been installed on Windows.

I've got a heap of different makes and models of phone that I'm swapping in and out.  Sometimes a phone that previously worked stops being recognised by `adb devices`.  So not really specific to a particular phone.

I've got a USB cable that I know works, for several makes/models of phone.

But still, when I get a new phone to try I still have to faff around with it to get it working.

What I'm after is a checklist of sorts, that results in a reasonable chance of success in getting `adb devices` to work.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I've found:

**Hardware**:

- Good USB cable - if it works for one phone it will probably
  work for others. If it consistently stops working, throw it away and
  get another.

**Phone/Tablet/Device - Pre-requisites**:

- Make sure the phone is charged up - at least 30% seems to be a common
  minimum.
- Get all system updates and app updates done.
- Enable Developer Mode. Settings->About phone->Build number - tap 7 times

**Computer - the 'turn it off and on again' approach**:

This is useful to know, but doesn't generally get things working. It goes like this:

`adb kill-server`

`adb start-server`

`adb devices`

If you don't see your device after `adb devices` then the above isn't the answer (but it's still good to know).

**Phone/Tablet/Device - the 'wipe it and start again' approach**:

This is basically clear your current settings and then re-establish them.

In `Developer options`, under `Debugging`:

- Turn OFF `USB debugging` (some phones won't let you click this option - thanks LG)
- Click/Tap `Revoke USB debugging authorizations`
- Turn ON `USB debugging`, answer `OK` to the first dialog

And if you device is already plugged in:

- WAIT, for a second prompt asking if you want 'Allow USB debugging' and click 'OK' - not every device will trigger this second prompt straight away, but give it 5 to 10 seconds just in case.

Now, get permission for EVERY use of the USB connection.

- Swipe down from the top and tap on the item for USB connection.
- Systematically work through every option your device provides and grant permission when asked.  Don't do just one option, do ALL of them, including `Charge phone`.

Having given permission for one of the usages of the USB connection some devices will give permission for everything - but most won't.  For the majority you should go through each one and give the permission.  Just to add to the confusion some devices will require you to revisit an option a second time before they give you the prompt asking for permission (thanks again LG).

Now try `adb devices` again.  Still nothing?  Go back through the USB usage options again from start to finish (I kid you not).

You may still need to reboot the device and/or swap between media transfer and photo transfer to get it showing up on `adb devices`.

So what if a previously working device stops working?  Go through the 'wipe it and start again' approach first.  It's likely to be the most effective. but I'd definitely check whether its time to retire the USB cable as well.